# Should I use Do or Does?

Tags: creative-writing, grammar

Hello:  Which is correct:  1) As the number of cases rise, so DOES John's suspicions. 2) As the number of cases rise, so DO John's suspicions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The first should end in "suspicion", without the S. The difference between the two is plurality, with the (non-proper) noun being conjugated in third person. It does. They do. Either should be appropriate, but context and pacing may make one more desirable over the other.

Comment: It's all about the English law of conservation of "S".

Answer (score 3):

I like #2. The subject for the verb is "suspicions" which is plural. So suspicions do rise rather than suspicions does rise.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking that too. Thanks!

Comment: Please mark as an answer, if you would.

Comment: "Suspicions" is a noun.

Comment: I strongly agree. We have two completing verb phrases "do rise" which is plural and and "does rise" which is singular. The subject (noun or equivalent) associated with the verb phrase is "suspicions". This is plural. The number of the verb phrase has to match, and thus "do rise" wins and "does rise" does not.